# Permissions to grant for a "sandbox" project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions

We're adding a GCP project to be used for greenfield development, e.g. sort of a developer sandbox.  My inclination is to give application/service developers full permissions in that project, to reduce friction and let them get stuff done as quickly and easily as possible.

We then have a separate `beta` project which we use where we prepare work for production, where application/service developers would have limited-to-no access, but the devops team could productionize things.  And then, of course, we have the `production` project, where everything is locked down tight.

Is a sandbox like this a good idea?  What permission(s) would I grant?  `Owner`?  GCP recommends not using those legacy roles...

Answer (score 0):

1. List all of what each team is allowed to do on each env.
2. Translate this to a list of IAM `permissions` per team per env.
3. If there is some predefined `role/s` that matches exactly these `permissions` then use that `role/s`
4. If not, then create your own custom `role/s` for each team per each env.

---

For example, in the *sandbox* env:

if developers team is only allowed to create `GKE` clusters and deploy `workloads` to these `GKE`s then list all required `permissions` for such operation and find a `predefined role` that have `permissions` that only allows this operation. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles).

Or, if this is too wide and does not apply the `least privilege concept` for you then create your own `custom role`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't recommend to restrict the IAM permission. Indeed, in a sandbox project, you want to try things, and maybe thing totally outside of the box and unexpected as usual way of working/processing. Using IAM to limit the set of allowed product restrict the creativity and protect you against (almost) nothing.

Indeed, if you want to perform security restriction it's for what? Limit the access to the service in Beta environment? Not sure... Prevent the overuse of resources in a non-production (and no profitable) environment? I think yes!

That's why, I recommend to use the [Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) to restrict the number of resources available for a project (i.e. only 10 CPUs in 1 region and not 3600 in 20 regions as by default). Like that, the app team will be able to try and experiment safely, without any restriction, but without killing your budget.

Comment: Even though what your saying make sense but sometimes you will have to use IAM to control even a Beta environment! cuz there might be two teams have to work together on same environment like a devops team and a developers team and you will need to organize who can do what so that they don't intercept each others work. Another example is if you are building the beta environment to be a pre-production environment which means you will create almost every resource just like in production to test your readiness to go live! applying quotas will not be a good idea in this case.